# Change Devise default route from provider method to create method in controller while using Omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, omniauth

I'm trying to use Devise and Omniauth to allow a user to sign in to multiple providers with a Rails 3.2 app. I got it to work but only if it goes to a twitter, facebook or tumblr method in the controller where I want all the providers to go to a create method. This is what I have the routes to do this: match '/auth/:provider/callback' => 'authentications#create'

```
  resources :authentications

  match '/auth/:provider/callback' => 'authentications#create'
  devise_for :users, path_names: {sign_in: "login", sign_out: "logout"},
    controllers: {omniauth_callbacks: "authentications"}

  root to: 'authentications#index'
```

My rake routes show:

```
 user_omniauth_authorize        /users/auth/:provider(.:format)        authentications#passthru {:provider=>/twitter|facebook|tumblr/}
  user_omniauth_callback        /users/auth/:action/callback(.:format) authentications#(?-mix:twitter|facebook|tumblr)
```

I want the user_omni_auth_callback route to to to authentications#create and not the specific providers. With the current setup, I get "The action 'twitter' could not be found for AuthenticationsController" because I'm not including it. What's the best way to do this?